# Custom Spring Boot login form

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to make my own custom login page for Spring boot. I just get "http://localhost:8080/login?error" and that's it. Can't debug anything in the console. No information at all. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Spring Boot and Java.

**login.html**

```
<div id="login-form-wrapper">
<form id="login-form" action="/login"  method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"
               aria-describedby="emailHelp" autofocus required/>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    <div id="no-account-wrapper">
        <small>Don't have an account?<a href="/registration"> Sign up</a></small>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginForm() {
    return "login";
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    final
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("myUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**", "/registration", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
        .successForwardUrl("/profile")
        .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure with the annotations @Configuration and @ComponentScan

**EDIT:**

Added registration.html and controller for the registration. Removed @ComponentScan from SecurityConfig

**registration.html**

```
<div id="registration-form-wrapper">
<form id="registration-form" th:action="@{'/perform_registration'}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}" id="first-name" required autofocus/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}" id="last-name" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="*{email}" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
               required/>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}" id="password" minlength="8" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{matchingPassword}" id="passwordRepeat" minlength="8"
               required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    <div id="no-account-wrapper">
        <small>Already have an account?<a href="login.html" th:href="@{'/'}"> Login</a></small>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller for registration**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    model.addAttribute("user", userDto);
    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/perform_registration", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute(name = "user") @Valid UserDto userDto, BindingResult result) {

    User existing = userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    if (existing != null) {
        log.info("User with email {} already exists -> {}", userDto.getEmail(), existing);
        result.rejectValue("email", "required", "User with email " + userDto.getEmail() + " already exists.");
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
    newUser.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
    newUser.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    newUser.setPassword(getPasswordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(newUser);

    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    final UserRepository userRepository;

    public MyUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(email));
        user.orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + email));

        return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@Configuration` yes, `@ComponentScan` no.

Comment: @Andreas Removed. Still the same. Idk what to do anymore..

Comment: Spring Security is configured to use `email` as the name of the property for the username. However in your login screen the name is `username` not `email`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I thought i had to define the type="email". Changed it to .usernameParameter("username"). Still the same.

Comment: When do you get this error? Can you see the login screen?

Comment: Yep. I just get this in the URL: "http://localhost:8080/login?error"

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` "indicates that the class has `@Bean` definition methods. So Spring container can process the class and generate Spring Beans to be used in the application." See more [here.](https://www.journaldev.com/21033/spring-configuration-annotation)

It is needed for your Security configuration class since it has some beans. You don't need  `@ComponentScan`.

Second following this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34174782/905494) of `@Bean` and `@Autowired`. You need to create your custom `UserDetailsService` which must have been implemented by your user entity (for authentication of users) as a bean and injected into your DAO authentication.

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

    return new CustomCustomerDetailsService();   
}



@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());   
    return authProvider;    
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58971101/905494) to know how to implement a custom user details class.

Complete Custom UserDetailsService

```
@Service("customCustomerDetailsService")
public class CustomCustomerDetailsService implements UserDetailsService  {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customers;    




    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)  {

      return this.customers.findByEmail(email)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username: " + email + " not found"));



    }

}
```

Comment: In EDIT 2 i have my UserDetailsService. Can you check this out?

Comment: You can simplify that thus: @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)  {
 
      return this.userRepository.findByEmail(email)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username: " + email + " not found"));
          
        
              
    }

Comment: Your User entity should implement UserDetails.

Comment: I did implement UserDetails. But when i try to implement your Override method above. I get a red warning on ".orElseThrow".
I did this:
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username: " + email + " not found"));
    }

Comment: I found the issue. I was sending the whole time null values because I didn't change my constructor to getEmail() and getPassword() in MyUserDetails. Such a dumb misstake. Thank you for your answer! I have a clearer picture of how all of this works.